# I want to change the custom back button in sherlock action bar and remove app icon

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I dont like the default back button that comes with action bars they look rather to tiny for my liking. I trying to fix a bigger and more descriptive button like the one used in the WeChat Mobile App.
please any body with an Idea.

I tried this below but did not work

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/back</item>  //Put in my style
```

The the one below in my code

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      //  actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

But did not work. the image that I kept in my drawable is not show. My app icon keeps show on the action bar which I dont want. and the back button is not working. Please any idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this :

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/new_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/new_indicator</item>
</style>
```

And `new_indicator` xml file in `drawable` folder: new_indicator.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="5dp">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/indicator" /> <!-- this is your desired image -->
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: After adding this that you suggested. I got the following errors

Comment: After adding this that you suggested. I got the following errors    09-20 07:37:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(416): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 07:37:20.078: E/AndroidRuntime(416): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jadehealthcare/com.example       @mansoulx

Comment: The Image has been changed. I noticed I did not place the new_indicator.xml in drawable folder. rather it was in drawable-v11. So I corrected it and image shows well now. But The only slight challenge is that the button is not working. How do I add functions to it

Comment: Thanks alot, I am really greatful. Your suggestion works like magic. I have also been able to add event to the back button. It perfect now.

Answer (score -1):

Replace the image of `indicator` with new one `indicator.png`.

You can find at your ( **project --> res --> drawable hdpi** )folder.

[image: this] to [image: this]

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do but if you're advocating replacing the image that ships with ActionBarSherlock, this would be a bad idea and wouldn't work on devices running GingerBread or less anyway.